# After sorting, it deletes the wrong line of primefaces datatable

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable with a column containing a commandButton to delete the associated line. When I sort the datatable and delete a line, it deletes the line that was at that position BEFORE the sort.

For example, suppose we have 5 lines in the datatable:

```
line 1 with id=12
line 2 with id=10
line 3 with id=25
line 4 with id=36
line 5 with id=1
```

Now suppose that I sort the lines by id. I obtain the lines:

```
line 1 with id=1 (previously line 5)
line 2 with id=10 (previously line 2)
line 3 with id=12 (previously line 1) <---------------
line 4 with id=25 (previously line 3)
line 5 with id=36 (previously line 4)
```

It's alright so far.

Now if I decide to delete **the line 3** it deletes **the line 1** which was at the position of the 3rd line **before the sort**

Here is my dataTable tag:

```
    <p:dataTable id="histoNotif" var="notif"
                    value="#{historiqueNotifController.listNotifications}"
                    paginator="true" rows="10"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20"
                    emptyMessage="No notifications"
                    rowStyleClass="#{notif.date==null ? 'new' : null}">
    ...
    </p:dataTable>
```

I hope I explained the problem clearly. Thank you.

---

Here is the code of the delete method:

```
public void delete(Notif notif) {
        try {
            notifService.deleteNotif(notif);
            listNotifs.remove(notif);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof DataIntegrityViolationException) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }  
    }
```

and the code of the button:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{notifController.delete(notif)}"
                        update=":formNotifs :formNotif"/>
```

Comment: Do you have code for the button + action(listener)?

Comment: Yes they are overridden already.. but it doesn't always delete the first row, it deletes the row that was at that position before the sort.

Comment: Try with rowkey="#{notif.id} or similar on the datatable

Comment: already tried that and it didn't worked

Comment: Can you try setting a `rowKey`, AND implementing an `equals` and `hashCode` on your `Notif` class? If id's are unique, `equals` _should_ use that id...

Comment: @rion18 I have tested again after adding `rowKey="#{notif.idnotif}"` and `equals and hashCode` methods for my class and it still delete the wrong row

Comment: no other idea about the issue plz?

Comment: Which Mojarra version are you using? A similar example works for me with glassfish and 2.2.0. Is the bean at least viewscoped?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem recently and after many hours trying to fix it it ended up that I was using:

```
javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
```

I swapped back to the following to finally solve the problem:

```
javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
```